# React RMWC - TopAppBar, Drawer and useState typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to control drawer from top menu by using useState. But when I'm using this in onNav seems like the burger menu stays as always clicked and the drawer is not changing. Looking into the console value is changing ok. What is interesting is that whey you will change it to normal boolean the burger menu not looks like frozen. Where is the problem?

I'd  like to have drawer open/close when I click burger menu, which should also behaves correctly

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { SimpleTopAppBar } from "@rmwc/top-app-bar";
import "@rmwc/top-app-bar/styles";
import "@rmwc/icon/styles";
import "@rmwc/drawer/styles";
import "@rmwc/list/styles";
import { Drawer, DrawerContent } from "@rmwc/drawer";
import { List, SimpleListItem } from "@rmwc/list";

function App() {
  const [isNavOpen, setIsNavOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <SimpleTopAppBar
        title="Test menu list"
        navigationIcon
        onNav={() => {
          setIsNavOpen(!isNavOpen);
          console.log(isNavOpen);
        }}
        actionItems={[
          {
            icon: "file_download",
            onClick: () => console.log("Do Something"),
          },
          //   { icon: "print", onClick: () => console.log("Do Something") },
          { icon: "login", onClick: () => console.log("Do Something") },
        ]}
      />
      <Drawer open={isNavOpen}>
        <DrawerContent>
          <List twoLine>
            <SimpleListItem
              graphic="star_border"
              text="Cookies"
              secondaryText="Chocolate chip"
              metaIcon="info"
            />
            <SimpleListItem
              graphic="local_pizza"
              text="Pizza"
              secondaryText="Pepperoni"
              metaIcon="info"
            />
            <SimpleListItem
              activated
              graphic="mood"
              text="Icecream"
              secondaryText="Chocolate cookie dough"
              meta="Winner!"
            />
          </List>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coa6D.png)

[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/affectionate-cohen-jmvczx?embed=1&file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx&showConsole=true&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00073j6j8flhjwef%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00023j6j2dnmvyjp%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00043j6jgtuh3o0j%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00063j6jij6u3xae%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqwov1yd00023j6j2dnmvyjp%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00013j6j2lymfqpj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00023j6j2dnmvyjp%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00013j6j2lymfqpj%2522%257D%252C%2522clqwov1yd00063j6jij6u3xae%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00053j6j83pmpswk%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00063j6jij6u3xae%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00053j6j83pmpswk%2522%257D%252C%2522clqwov1yd00043j6jgtuh3o0j%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00043j6jgtuh3o0j%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00033j6jf4bqm8ip%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwov1yd00033j6jf4bqm8ip%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwoz4yq00g33j6jh1gr8jlu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clqwoz5100097ecipafqigbac%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Answer (score 0):

Add dismissible prop to drawer component.

```
 <Drawer dismissible open={isNavOpen}>
```

Comment: Saldy doesnt change much. It still "freeze" after first two clicks

Comment: i have made it work but don't think its a perfect solution you have go through there documentation properly, you can check your codesandbox